# Is most higher level math written in English?

Tags: research

There are many math journals published in English. Are there a lot of math journals written in Chinese, Russian, German, French, etc. they have no English translation? Are they only accessible to those who speak and read those languages? Could there be non-English written mathematics at the higher level that would not have an English counterpart? Could there be math in the world that would be “new” to English speakers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that there are old articles that are not available in English (especially in Russian, German or French), but nowadays basically everything is written in English, with very few exceptions (there are still some articles written in French for instance). I guess the main exception would be thesis manuscripts, that are not uncommonly written in the local language of the PhD student (especially in countries where this is mandatory).

Comment: So do Chinese universities and Russian universities require their phd student to write their thesis in English?